# Changing fill of legend shape in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a rather complicated plot that shows three different variables in my data - see the example plot below. I've removed one of the legends and am trying to show the `consonant` colours more clearly by filling in the squares. I've tried using `guide_legend(override.aes())` but I can't find a way to adjust the colours on this. Is there a way to do it?

The sample data is:

```
 exampledata <- tribble(~subject, ~group, ~time, ~consonant, ~type,  ~n,
                   "1", "A", 1, "p", F, 10,
                   "1", "A", 1, "t", T, 12,
                   "1", "A", 1, "k", T, 50,
                   "2", "A", 1, "p", T, 0,
                   "2", "A", 1, "t", T, 45,
                   "2", "A", 1, "k", F, 23,
                   "2", "A", 2, "p", F, 2,
                   "2", "A", 2, "t", T, 34,
                   "2", "A", 2, "k", T, 56,
                   "3", "B", 1, "p", F, 12,
                   "3", "B", 1, "t", T, 13,
                   "3", "B", 1, "k", F, 50,
                   "4", "A", 1, "p", T, 10,
                   "4", "A", 1, "t", F, 12,
                   "4", "A", 1, "k", T, 50,
                   "5", "B", 1, "p", T, 0,
                   "5", "B", 1, "t", T, 24,
                   "5", "B", 1, "k", F, 3,
                   "5", "B", 2, "p", F, 23,
                   "5", "B", 2, "t", F, 12,
                   "5", "B", 2, "k", T, 7,
                   "6", "A", 1, "p", F, 52,
                   "6", "A", 1, "t", F, 12,
                   "6", "A", 1, "k", T, 64
 )
```

And the `ggplot` code that I have so far:

```
 exampleplot <- ggplot(exampledata, aes(x = time, y=n, 
                       fill=type, colour = consonant))  +  
   geom_col(lwd = 1, aes(linetype = group)) +
   scale_linetype_manual(values = c("A" = "solid", 
                                    "B" = "twodash"), guide = F) +
   facet_grid(~subject, scales = "free_x", switch = "x") + 
   scale_fill_manual(values=c("gray97", "gray77"), 
                     labels = c("Type 1", "Type 2")) +
   theme_bw(base_size = 18) + 
   theme(strip.text.x = element_text(angle=75),
         axis.text.x  = element_blank(),
         axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
         panel.border =element_blank(),
         strip.background = element_blank())

 plot(exampleplot)
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: why not `fill = consonent` and `alpha = type` in the aes?

Comment: is the x-axis `time` or `subject`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exampleplot <- ggplot(exampledata, aes(x = time, y=n, 
                       alpha=type, fill = consonant, color = consonant))  +  
   geom_col(lwd = 1, aes(linetype = group)) +
   scale_linetype_manual(values = c("A" = "solid", 
                                    "B" = "twodash"), guide = F) +
   facet_grid(~subject, scales = "free_x", switch = "x") + 
   scale_alpha_discrete(range=c(0.4,0.8), 
                    labels = c("Type 1", "Type 2")) +
   theme_bw(base_size = 18) + 
   theme(strip.text.x = element_text(angle=75),
         axis.text.x  = element_blank(),
         axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
         panel.border =element_blank(),
         strip.background = element_blank())

 plot(exampleplot)
```

I added a `fill` in the `aes` and `alpha` to keep the differences between `Type`. Is this the output you want with filled squared?

[image]

Comment: This works, but it isn't quite what I need because of the need to show `linetype` - the filled blocks make it difficult to see which linetype is used for each column.

Comment: @CatherineLaing can play with the values of alpha to get the desired contrast. I corrected the graph to better see the linetypes

Comment: Ok this looks good - thank you! I adjusted the alpha scale to (0.2, 0.6) and it looks how I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ggplot(exampledata, aes(x = time, y=n, 
                                       fill=type, colour = consonant))  +  
  geom_col(lwd = 1, aes(linetype = group)) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = c("#F8766D", "#00BA38", "#619CFF")))) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("A" = "solid", 
                                   "B" = "twodash"), guide = F) +
  facet_grid(~subject, scales = "free_x", switch = "x") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("gray97", "gray77"), 
                    labels = c("Type 1", "Type 2")) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 18) + 
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(angle=75),
        axis.text.x  = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        panel.border =element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank())
```

If have added this line:

```
guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = c("#F8766D", "#00BA38", "#619CFF"))))
```

[image]

Comment: I did try this but my problem is that I have 5 consonant variables in my real data, so it got a bit clumsy!